# Get contents of array from string containing name of array

Tags: arrays, string, bash, dereference

Let's say I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

arrayName_1=( 3 4 5 )
arrayName_2=( 0 1 2 )
str="arrayName_1"
arrayName=?
```

In the end, I want arrayName variable to be an array containing 3, 4, 5, just like arrayName_1. How do I make this happen? I know I could do the below, but I have to use str instead of arrayName_1:

```
arrayName=("${arrayName_1[@]}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
arrayName_1=( 3 4 5 )
arrayName_2=( 0 1 2 )
name="arrayName_1"
indirect=$name"[@]"
arrayName=("${!indirect}")
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted.